# Handler postDelayed runnable how to know time till start?

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable

I have a Handler and a runnable to be done in 3000ms when I touch the screen.

How can I display the time left to happen since I touched the screen?

Is there any way to display it on a `textview` or something alike?

Comment: I don't think the Handler itself has any kind of `getTimeUntil()` type method that will tell you. So you'd have to keep track of the time separately yourself in order to display it back to the user.

Comment: Why not use asynctask. It has onprogressupdate method which allows you to post progress. Yes you can use a textview .

Comment: Thanks both, i will look for info of asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a counter value and increase it by 1000. Then rather using `postDelayed(3000)` you can use `postDelayed(1000)`.

Every time the runnable is called, increase the counter with 1000 until it became the expected value (3000 in this case). Then do you work and return.